# On the rate of convergence of nested radicals

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics, radicals

The sequence of nested radicals $\sqrt {a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+...}}}$ is defined by

$x_1=\sqrt a$,   $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{a+x_n}$,   where $a>0$.

Here are three questions:

> **(a)** Show that $x=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}$.
>
> **(b)** Prove $\displaystyle x-x_n\sim \frac{C_a}{(2x)^n}$ for some $C_a>0.$
>
> **(c)** For $a=2$, what is the value of $C_2$ in **(b)**?

My attempt:

**(a)** is easy. It is easy to prove $\{x_n\}$ is monotone and bounded, hence $x=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$ exists. Then we have the equation $x^2-x-a=0$.

For **(b)**, I start by writing:

\begin{align}
x-x_n &= \frac{x^2-x_n^2}{x+x_n} \\
&= \frac{(x+a)-(x_{n-1}+a)}{x+x_n} \\
&= \frac{x-x_{n-1}}{x+x_n}
\end{align}

By induction,

$$x-x_n= \frac{x}{\prod_{k=1}^n (x+x_k)}$$

and I got stuck at this step.

For **(c)**, once we prove $\displaystyle x_n=2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)$, it is not hard to see the constant $C_2$ is equal to $\displaystyle \frac{\pi^2}{4}$. This is a standard example of trigonometric substitution.

> Any idea on how to tackle **(b)**?

Notation: $f(n)\sim g(n)$ if and only if $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_n:=x-h_n$, so that $$(x-h_{n+1})^2=a+x-h_n$$ which simplifies to $$h_{n+1}^2-2xh_{n+1}+h_n=0$$ \begin{align*}h_{n+1}&=x-\sqrt{x^2-h_n}\\
&=\frac{h_n}{2x}(1+\frac{h_n}{4x^2}+\frac{h_n^2}{8x^4}+\cdots)\\
\end{align*}

So multiplying out gives $$h_n=\frac{h_1}{(2x)^n}\prod_{k=1}^n(1+\frac{h_k}{4x^2}+\frac{h_k^2}{8x^4}+\cdots)$$ so the required constant is $$C_a=h_1\prod_{k=1}^n(1+\frac{h_k}{4x^2}+\frac{h_k^2}{8x^4}+\cdots)$$

This constant need not have a closed formula but it exists by standard results on convergence of products.

Comment: Sorry, how do we have $
\left(x-h_{n+1}\right)^{2}=a+x-h_{n}
$? This is wrong for $a=2$.

Comment: It's just $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{a+x_n}$.

Comment: Just try an example, you will see it is false.

Comment: I don't understand. It's what you wrote in the second line. It's the definition of $x_{n+1}$, so how can it be false?

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. Still, the conclusion must be wrong. The constant $C_a$ cannot be equal to $h_1$, as in the case $a=2$ (see **(c)**), $C_a=\frac{\pi^2}{4}$, while $h_1=2-\sqrt 2$.

Comment: I tried to clarify the argument. I did not claim $C_a=h_1$, but I used the wrong notation for $\sim$.

Comment: Understood. Thanks!